# How to dim block environments in beamer

Tags: beamer, environments

One of my beamer slides looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

\begin{block}{Theorem}
Theorem 1.
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}{Theorem}
Theorem 2.
\end{block}
\pause

\begin{block}{Theorem}
Theorem 3.
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So as written, it shows Theorem 1 on the top of the page, then the theorem disappears, then it shows Theorem 2 in the middle of the page, then the theorem disappears, then it shows Theorem 3 on the bottom of the page.

What I would like it to do is show all three theorems on the page, but with the last two blocks dimmed out. When I change slides, I would like it to now dim the first theorem and brighten/emphasize the second block. Finally, I would like it to dim the second theorem and brighten the last theorem. How do I do this? If the question is unclear, I can clarify it. Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Could you convert your code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

[image]

This is  done by setting `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` in the preamble. Also, instead of using `\pause`, use `<#>` at the block environment to set the overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{block}<1>{Theorem}
Theorem 1.
\end{block}

\begin{block}<2>{Theorem}
Theorem 2.
\end{block}

\begin{block}<3>{Theorem}
Theorem 3.
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use for example `\setbeamercovered{dynamic}` (see section *17.6
Transparency Effect* in Beamer manual) and an overlay command as `\onslide`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\onslide<1>{\begin{block}{Theorem} Theorem 1. \end{block}}
\onslide<2>{\begin{block}{Theorem} Theorem 2. \end{block}}
\onslide<3>{\begin{block}{Theorem} Theorem 3. \end{block}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As showed by Kevin C, some  environments as `block` and commands as `\item` can be followed simply by `<range of slides>` to obtain the same effect, but `\onslide<range of slides>{}` as well as other overlays commands could be used for any chunk of your frame. See sections *3.10 Using Overlay Specifications* and *9 Creating Overlays* in the Beamer manual.